# Sending base64String over http post ends up null serverside in C#

Tags: c#, image, httpwebrequest

I have a console application that encodes an image as base64String and then sends it to a server as part of an http POST request.

Problem is, when I open it up to examine it server side, the data is no longer there.

Here is the code I'm using to send the string-

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(ip);
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.Method = "POST";
string formPostString = "image=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(imageBase64String);
byte[] buffer = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formPostString);
webRequest.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
using (Stream webStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    webStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

And the code I have handling it serverside-

```
private void OnRequest(object source, RequestEventArgs args)
{
    IHttpClientContext context = (IHttpClientContext)source;
    IHttpRequest request = args.Request;

    ImageConverter imgConvert = new ImageConverter();
    string imageBase64String = request.Form["image"].Value;
    Image newImg = imgConvert.Base64StringToImage(imageBase64String);
    newImg.Save(@"..\Images\test.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

When it reaches the point of making the new Image object, the imageBase64String is null. I can't seem to identify why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client code you have shown never sends a request. You must call `webRequest.GetResponse()` for the request to be sent. But I would simplify this client code suing a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var data = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "image", imageBase64String }
    };
    var result = client.UploadValues(ip, data);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(result));
}
```

As far as your server side code is concerned you seem to be using some third party framework which you haven't mentioned in your question. For example the following ASP.NET handler works perfectly fine (`~/UploadImage.ashx`) with the client shown previously:

```
public class UploadImage : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var imageBase64String = context.Request.Form["image"];
        var imageBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(imageBase64String);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(imageBuffer))
        using (var image = Image.FromStream(stream))
        {
            image.Save(@"c:\work\test.png");
        }

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("upload successful");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

But if we are going to upload files to a server, why reinventing wheels? Why using base64 when there's [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) with a wheel reinvented Base64 encoding which hugely increases the request size when there's [`multipart/form-data`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2)?

So let's improve our client to take advantage of this specifically designed for the purpose encoding. Let's start by writing an extension method for the WebClient which will allow us to directly upload one or more files:

```
public class UploadFile
{
    public UploadFile()
    {
        ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public Stream Stream { get; set; }
}

public static class WebClientExtensions
{
    public static byte[] UploadFiles(this WebClient client, string address, IEnumerable<UploadFile> files, NameValueCollection values)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(address);
        request.Method = "POST";
        var boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        boundary = "--" + boundary;

        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            // Write the values
            foreach (string name in values.Keys)
            {
                var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(boundary + Environment.NewLine);
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"{1}{1}", name, Environment.NewLine));
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(values[name] + Environment.NewLine);
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            // Write the files
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(boundary + Environment.NewLine);
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"{2}", file.Name, file.Filename, Environment.NewLine));
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("Content-Type: {0}{1}{1}", file.ContentType, Environment.NewLine));
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                file.Stream.CopyTo(requestStream);
                buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            var boundaryBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(boundary + "--");
            requestStream.Write(boundaryBuffer, 0, boundaryBuffer.Length);
        }

        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            responseStream.CopyTo(stream);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

and then the client will look like this:

```
byte[] image = ... go and fetch the image that you want to upload

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(image))
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var files = new[]
    {
        new UploadFile
        {
            Name = "image",
            Filename = "test.jpg",
            ContentType = "image/jpg",
            Stream = stream
        }
    };
    var result = client.UploadFiles("http://localhost:6830/uploadimage.ashx", files, new NameValueCollection());
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(result));
}
```

and the server we handler we have seen earlier:

```
public class UploadImage : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var uploadedImage = context.Request.Files["image"];
        using (var image = Image.FromStream(uploadedImage.InputStream))
        {
            image.Save(@"c:\work\test.png");
        }

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("upload successful");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Guess, what the next step in improvement of this code is? Answer: an asynchronous client request of course that will take advantage of I/O Completion Ports instead of blocking the calling thread while waiting for the file to be uploaded to the server.

Comment: I suppose I should have added more context. The other problem is that I can't count on being able to use .Net-specific classes or frameworks or anything of the like, because eventually the same system is going to be used to get an image from an iPhone app being developed by co-worker. I do appreciate what you've posted, but the biggest obstacle here is that this is a proof of concept, and the final product won't have both ends working with ASP.NET capabilities.

Comment: Then what is the problem? The server side is ASP.NET, the client side could be anything. On the server you support the `multipart/form-data` standard which every client could support. I have shown an example for a .NET client. But you could send a `multipart/form-data` encoded request from absolutely any type of client.

Comment: All right, I simply was not aware of what was specific to ASP.NET and what wasn't, this is a bit of a new realm of coding to me. Thanks for all the assistance!